# Meteor apk :Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'diagnostic' of undefined

Tags: cordova, meteor

I am using Cordova diagnostic plugin. i wrote the code like below as mentioned in plugin github readme
But i am getting error in terminal while running cordova app as shown below:Uncaught TypeError:Cannot read Property 'diagnostic' of undefined. But it works fine on web.

```
       if (Meteor.isCordova) {
// check and request microphone access
cordova.plugins.diagnostic.getMicrophoneAuthorizationStatus(function(status) {
    if (status !== "GRANTED") {
      // if we don't have them request em.
      cordova.plugins.diagnostic.requestMicrophoneAuthorization(function(status) {
        //... do something
        return;
      });
    }
}, function() {
  throw new Meteor.error('failed to get permission for microphone');
});
```

}

Comment: What device are you testing on - Android or iOS? And are you waiting for the `deviceready` event to fire before running this code?

Comment: @DaveAlden I am using a android device and I am not waiting for deviceready event to get triggered.

Comment: @dpatnaik very nice question.. so interesting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am not waiting for deviceready event to get triggered.

That'll be why it's not working. The JS elements of plugins are loaded dynamically at runtime by Cordova, hence are not guaranteed to be loaded until the `deviceready` event has fired, which signals the Cordova environment has finished setting up.

In Meteor, you do this using the `Meteor.startup()` function:

```
if (Meteor.isCordova) {
    // Wait for deviceready
    Meteor.startup(function () {
        // check and request microphone access
        cordova.plugins.diagnostic.getMicrophoneAuthorizationStatus(function(status) {
            if (status !== "GRANTED") {
              // if we don't have them request em.
              cordova.plugins.diagnostic.requestMicrophoneAuthorization(function(status) {
                //... do something
                return;
              });
            }
        }, function() {
          throw new Meteor.error('failed to get permission for microphone');
        });
    });
}
```